# Como hacer varias consultas para un ciclo WHILE y mostrar en una tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, while

Les comento, quiero hacer una tabla dinámica mediante consultas, que ordena los productos, como producción si se ingresaron hoy, como inventario si se ingresaron antes de hoy y las ventas, la estructura es así:

```
--------------------------------------
|ID          |AUTO INCREMENT Primary |
|------------|-----------------------|
|ProductoID  |Index                  |
|------------|-----------------------|
|UsuarioID   |Index, Puede ser NULL  |
|------------|-----------------------|
|Qty         |INT                    |
|------------|-----------------------|
|Fecha       |DATE                   |
|------------------------------------|
```

ProductoID, y UsuarioID se relacionan con otras 2 tablas, el problema es que al momento de llamar las consultas para comparar, tengo que hacer varias consultas para sumar solo lo perteneciente a un ProductoID, les comparto mi código:

```
<?php

$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT Inv.ProductoID, Pro.Nombre_Producto FROM Inventario AS Inv INNER JOIN Productos AS Pro ON Inv.ProductoID = Pro.ID');
$statement->execute();


while($inventario = $statement->fetch() ) { ?>

<?php
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT Inv.ProductoID, Pro.Nombre_Producto FROM Inventario AS Inv INNER JOIN Productos AS Pro ON Inv.ProductoID = Pro.ID');
$statement->execute();
$inventario_datos = $statement->fetch();

$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha < CURRENT_DATE AND Qty > 0 AND ProductoID = :ProductoID');
$statement->execute(array(":ProductoID"=>$inventario_datos["ProductoID"]));
$inventario_actual = $statement->fetch();

$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha = CURRENT_DATE AND Qty > 0 AND ProductoID = :ProductoID');
$statement->execute(array(":ProductoID"=>$inventario_datos["ProductoID"]));
$produccion = $statement->fetch();

$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Inventario WHERE Qty < 0 AND ProductoID = :ProductoID');
$statement->execute(array(":ProductoID"=>$inventario_datos["ProductoID"]));
$ventas = $statement->fetch();
              ?>     

                    <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $inventario_datos["Nombre_Producto"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $inventario_actual["SUM(Qty)"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $produccion["SUM(Qty)"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $ventas["SUM(Qty)"]*-1; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $inventario_actual["SUM(Qty)"] + $produccion["SUM(Qty)"] + $ventas["SUM(Qty)"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                          
                      <?php $inventario++; } ?>
```

y la cuestión es que, o solo me muestra un producto (deberían ser 3) o me muestra solo uno pero repetido y al hacer var_dump de los ID solo aparece 1, les comparto mi ultimo intento:
[image: Intento 23 donde solo aparece un producto pero con sus numeros correctos]

Ya valida la fecha correctamente y los demas campos, pero sigue mostrando solo 1, espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: En mysql, cuántos registros te devuelve la primera consulta? Además si la consulta de productos tiene más de un registro siempre va a imprimir un registro porque no tienes un `while` de esa consulta.

Comment: @Bicho la primera me devuelve 3 ID, pero como vez intente ponerla en el while

Comment: Estas ejecutando siempre la misma consulta.. la segunda no deberia llevar un where?

Comment: @gbianchi Podrias indicarme en que parte de consulta

Comment: Deberías dividir tu problema y tu pregunta: creo que tu proceso se facilitaría mucho si, en una sola consulta sql, te trajera toda esa información. Pregunta en mysql cómo podrías hacerlo. Una vez tengas esa consulta, mostrarla en pantalla sería más sencillo.

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras Una vez mas estas ayudandome en mis extraordinarios problemas, sobre tu consejo creeme que lo he intentado pero sin resultados, y estoy desesperado porque es algo que debo entregar

Comment: LA segunda consulta, dentro del where es exactamente igual a la primera.. no se que tratas de hacer, pero si no le agregas que estas buscando en la segunda (con un where) siempre vas a traer los mismos registros.. probaste como te dijeron, hacerlo primero en mysql?

Comment: @gbianchi se ahora en que parte te refieres, mira primero le pido que me sume solo los registros que tiene fecha anterior a hoy y solo los que su ID sea igual a los ID que me trae la primera consulta y si lo probe en mysql, y todo OK pero en el codigo no lo logro hacer

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar brevemente **lo que quieres hacer**, independientemente de **cómo lo quieres hacer**? Como ha dicho @AntonioVenerosoContreras podrías obtener toda la información que requieres una una sola consulta, relacionando las tablas, y luego leer es único conjunto de resultados. El problema es que en la pregunta no se entiende exactamente lo que quieres hacer, pero viendo tantas consultas casi similares es casi seguro que no has optado por la forma más óptima de resolver este problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
<?php

$sql="SELECT Pro.ProductoID, Pro.Nombre_Producto, inventario_actual.TOT_INVENTARIO_ACTUAL,  produccion.tot_produccion, VENTAS.tot_ventas ".
"FROM Productos AS PRO ".
"LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProductoID, SUM(Qty) TOT_INVENTARIO_ACTUAL FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha < CURRENT_DATE AND Qty > 0 GROUP BY ProductoID ) inventario_actual ON inventario_actual.ProductoID =PRO.ID ".
"LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProductoID, SUM(Qty) tot_produccion FROM Inventario WHERE Fecha = CURRENT_DATE AND Qty > 0 GROUP BY ProductoID) produccion ON produccion.ProductoID=PRO.ID ".
"LEFT JOIN (SELECT ProductoID, SUM(Qty) tot_ventas FROM Inventario WHERE Qty < 0 GROUP BY ProductoID ) VENTAS ON VENTAS.ProductoID =PRO.ID ".
"WHERE pro.ID IN (SELECT ProductoID  from Inventario )"
// Falta le agreges el orden que desees/prefieras mostrarlo
;

$statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();

while ($rs= $statement->fetch()) {

 ?>     

   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $rs["Nombre_Producto"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rs["TOT_INVENTARIO_ACTUAL"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rs["tot_produccion"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rs["tot_ventas"]*-1; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rs["TOT_INVENTARIO_ACTUAL"] + $rs["tot_produccion"] + $rs["tot_ventas"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
<?php
// lo que aplique para tí

}
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Amigo que significa ese TOT

Comment: "abreviacion" de TOTAL

Comment: Ahhh, los estoy probando pero sin duda mis respetos amigo

Comment: amigo ahora no me muestra nada

Comment: Saludos. Prueba `var_dump($rs)`; debe salir algo como `àrray(N) = {"Nombre_Producto"=>"algo", "TOT_INVENTARIO_ACTUAL"=>UnNumero, ...}` para comprobar que datos hay en `$rs` cada ciclo; así como si se repite al menos una vez. Si le agregaste algo después del `WHERE` mira si no quedo pegado que este causando error. Acabo de notar `SELECT Pro.ProductoID,` al inicio del SQL debe ser `SELECT Pro.ID AS ProductoID,`

Comment: Ya amigo lo adapte una que otra cosilla pero ya quedo gracias eres un master